# Python 3 IF statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Can someone help me with this error?

```
quantity = int(input('enter the the quantity:'))

if quantity>=10 and quantity<=19:

print('20% off')
discount=99*0.2
print('discount ', discount)
purchase= quantity*99-dicount
print('purchase is ', purchase)
```

it says line 5 
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Indentiation matters in Python. You have to indent code to place it inside an `if` loop.

Comment: It means: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Please do your own research before asking questions. Simply googling your error message would have led you to thousands of tutorials, posts and articles which describe the problem, its causes, and the solution. Furthermore, you are expected to have a minimal understanding of the language you program in before asking questions on SO about it - the fact that you don't know the very basics of python (control flow is handled by indentation) means you are lacking this minimal understanding and should go read some tutorials or books before asking any further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if quantity>=10 and quantity<=19:

    print('20% off')
    discount=99*0.2
    print('discount ', discount)
    purchase= quantity*99-dicount
    print('purchase is ', purchase)
```

python uses indentation to define code blocks. you have if statement but not indented block below it, that could be conditioned

for better explanation, in this pseudo-code:

```
if condition: 
    do A
    do B
do C
do D
```

the A and B will depend on condition, but C and D will not. you need at least one indented command after if statement. it might be simple return if you have nothing to put in yet